# Trying to weight some stats from a game for a custom scoring system

Tags: average

I recently made a Discord bot for a leaderboard around a game called PUBG. I made my own fun "score" to promote team-based stats (versus just win rate) but I believe I have a fatal flaw in my desired logic.

My intention is to use three stats and take their average to give you this score. The stats are your **win rate**, **KDA** (kill death assists), and your **teammate revival**. All of these being your average per game.

I planned on weighing:

- Win rate at 3x
- KDA at 1x
- Teammate revival at 0.25x.

*I also at the end multiply by 10,000 to make the number look more leaderboard-esque versus a single digit number.*

My problem, is that I believe KDA is getting a massive sway over this average as you will see in my example below.

Player 1 has a score of: **~6,570**

Player 2 has a score of: **~4,220**

Player 1's stats and current calculations are:

> Win/Matches (0/ 31) = 0(0%) Weighted at 3x = **~0.000**
>
> KDA (54 / 16 / 31) = **~1.914**
>
> *KDA as ((Kills+Assists/3)/Deaths)*
>
> Teammate revives per match: (7 / 31) = ~0.226 Weighted at 0.25x =
>   **~0.057**
>
> ---
>
> Winrate + KDA + Revives is divided by 3 (for the three factors) to get
>   an average of: **~ 0.657**.
>
> We multiply it by 10,000 for a total score of: **~6,570**

Player 2's stats and current calculations are:

> Win/Matches (3 / 98) = 0.030 (3%) Weighted at 3x = **~0.090**
>
> KDA (93 / 45 / 98) = **~1.102**
>
> *KDA as ((Kills+Assists/3)/Deaths)*
>
> Teammate revives per match: (29 / 99) = ~0.293 Weighted at 0.25x =
>   **~0.073**
>
> ---
>
> Winrate + KDA + Revives is divided by 3 (for the three factors) to get
>   an average of: **~ 0.422**.
>
> we multiply it by 10,000 for a total score of: **~4,220**

From looking at this Player 2 has a better win rate than Player 1, yet Player 1 has a far better score. I noticed that both the revive and winrate stats are numbers such as `0.0xx`, while KDA is a `1.xxx` number. This  means KDA will always have a much stronger sway on the combined score, when really it should be the win rate.

My question, is how can I go about correcting my calculations to meet my desired weights? Is there a mathematically correct way or is it just to start inflating winrate to a point where it looks like it is getting the 3x weight it deserves.

**Background**:

These stats are based off 4-man squads in a 100-player battle royal. Only 1 team per round can win (so roughly 25 teams per match). Maybe this will help in figuring out a better score/weight for my use. As maybe giving win rate a 3x weight isn't doing enough justice for how hard it is.

Thank you!

Comment: Where do you get the KDA numbers from? I get the KDA for player 1 as $\frac{(54+16)/3}{31} = 0.753$, and for player 2 as $\frac{(93+45)/3}{98} = 0.469$.

Comment: @TobyMak the /3 is on assists only, so assists are weighted at a 1/3. So it is (54+(16/3))/31 for player 1 as an example

Comment: Well, one solution could be to take the [geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean). For example, for player $1$ it would be $(0 \cdot 1.914 \cdot 0.057)^{1/3} = 0$, and for player $2$ it would be $(0.090 \cdot 1.102 \cdot 0.073)^{1/3} = 0.193$. The advantage of this is that if you score zero for any one of the categories, your score would also be zero.

Comment: @TobyMak I like that! Any idea on not entirely 0'ing out players with no wins?

Comment: You could add $0.001$ to each value, take the logarithms of each value, take the averages of these values, and then take the antilogarithm. For example, for player $1$ it would be $\frac{\log_{10}(0.001) + \log_{10}(1.915) + \log_{10}(0.058)}{3} = -1.132$, and $10^{-1.132} = 0.048$.